# How to get the bounds using content description and perform long click

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I've a uiobject named "Gallery". I want to click this Uiobject using Bounds. 
Current method i'm following: Getting the height and width of the device using getDisplayHeight/width() then depends on the phone height and width i am clicking the Uiobject bounds.The problem i am facing is if change the hardware which is bigger screen the bounds/coordinates will change.To overcome this, is it possible to get the bounds of this Uiobject("Gallery") and perform long click?

How to get bounds using the content description and perform long click?

```
  UiObject obj1 = new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("Gallery"));
```

I've a Uiobject with content description named "Gallery". Is it possible to get the bounds of this Uiobject("Gallery") and perform long click?

Comment: man, what are you talking about?

Comment: I've a uiobject named "Gallery". I want to click this Uiobject using Bounds. Current method i'm following: Getting the height and width of the device using getDisplayHeight/width() then depends on the device height and width i'm clicking the Uiobject coordinates.The problem i am facing is if change the phone which is bigger screen the bounds/coordinates will change.To overcome this, is it possible to get the bounds of this Uiobject("Gallery") and perform long click?

Comment: ah ok, its uiautomator... sorry for confusion

Comment: I find the solution and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

We can do in this way

```
UiObject descriptionElement = new UiObject(new UiSelector().description("your description"));
        Rect bounds = descriptionElement.getBounds();
        int x = bounds.centerX();
        int y = bounds.centerY();
        getUiDevice().click(x, y);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly UiDevice does not have any longpress methord, it only supports click(). if using coordinates is not a requirment for you, you can do longpress on an object like this:

UiObject descriptionElement = new UiObject(new UiSelector().description("your description"));
descriptionElement.longClick();